# How to change UITableViewCell's origin value at Size Inspector on storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How can I change `UITableViewCell`'s origin property at Size Inspector in storyboard? For some reasons `UITableViewCell`'s origin property cannot be altered on the Inspector. To make it more worse, the origin property is never set at fixed value - when I pull `UITableViewCell` from Object Library and put it on storyboard, the result varies depending on some factors, which I don't know about, such as `y = 86`, `y = 119`, `y = 22`, etc...

Why does the `UITableViewCell` act like in such a awful way? And why does it not even allow me to change its property value?

Since the value is not fixed, sometimes my table view cell is buried under navigation bar, and the first cell or the header of the first section cannot be displayed to users.

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `UITableViewCell` does not have an origin property.  It has frame and bounds properties, inherited from `UIView`.  If you're referring to the origin *field* of either frame or bounds, then you're almost certainly trying to solve your problem in the wrong place.

`UITableViewCells` are intended to be shown in a `UITableView`.  Chances are, if your first `UITableViewCell` is obstructed by another view then the frame of your `UITableView` is at fault.  Make sure the `UITableView` frame does not overlap any other views.

Comment: My `UITableView` doesn't overlap other views - it's disturbed only by navigation bar. So what I should do is move my `UITableView`'s `y` frame value by the height of navigation bar?

Comment: ```UINavigationBar``` is a view, so yes, your ```UITableView's``` ```frame.origin.y``` should probably be your ```UINavigationBar's``` ```frame.origin.y+frame.size.height```.

Comment: Then why do I have to change its value ONLY WHEN I have multiple table views in a single view controller? Even if my table view's frame values are `x = 0, y = 0`, as long as it is the only table view in my view controller, it doesn't overlap navigation bar.

Comment: It's certainly possible that you have some constraints adjusting the layout.

Comment: I tried to run it with and without autolayout, but wasn't able to solve the issue. So I gave up using it on storyboard and instead wrote everything related to the tables in code, and saw it work properly. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @Gardecolo could you please share the code to decrement or remove the captured origin y position of view?